# Gridview to display after updating

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, web-controls

I'm using bulk update to update my gridview.

The user is first prompted to select dates and then click a button to display the gridview data for those dates. Update the relevant cells and then click on save.

The thing is my Gridview disappears after it gets updated. 
I want the Gridview to remain displaying the updated data. 
How do I do that?

Code Snippets:

```
 string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["bbsConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {

            SqlDataAdapter sdr = new SqlDataAdapter(str, Con);

            sdr.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdate", startdate);
            sdr.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddate", enddate);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sdr.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
                Button2.Visible = true;
            }



        }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {



            TextBox dtm = row.FindControl("DtmTextBox") as TextBox;


            string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["bbsConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(connStr))
            {
                Con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update tblAvailable set intqty=@intQty, curprice=@curprice where intresortid=@intresortid and dtm=@dtm and strroomtype=@strroomtype", Con);



                // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtm", DateTime.ParseExact(dtm.Text.Trim(), "dd/M/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
                GridView1.DataBind();
                GridView1.Visible = true;




            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign datatable/DataSet to data source before bind method is called

```
 GridView1.DataSource = dt;
 GridView1.DataBind();
```

Here you are binding grid after update but not assigning DataTable to GridView1.DataSource. You can call the DataGrid method here instead of binding like this.

```
private void FillGrid()
{
string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["bbsConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {

            SqlDataAdapter sdr = new SqlDataAdapter(str, Con);

            sdr.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdate", startdate);
            sdr.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddate", enddate);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sdr.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
                Button2.Visible = true;
            }
        }
}
 //You should as call the method FillGrid that loads data and bind grid previously      

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            //GridView1.DataBind();
            FillGrid();
            GridView1.Visible = true;
```

Remove these statement and call method which bind the grid previously

Comment: Except that datatable dt in button1_click while the update is being done in button1_click

Comment: Make method for load and filling data in grid like FillGrid() and call after update statement and where ever you need to fill grid

Comment: Do you have an example, please

Comment: I have updated my answer I hope it will help you loading data

Answer (score 0):

I have Already used below code . I will work .you should call again that Method in which you are displaying Grid view by date

```
public void DisplyGridview(){

string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["bbsConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {

        SqlDataAdapter sdr = new SqlDataAdapter(str, Con);

        sdr.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdate", startdate);
        sdr.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddate", enddate);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sdr.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            Button2.Visible = true;
          }



    }
```

}
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{

```
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {



        TextBox dtm = row.FindControl("DtmTextBox") as TextBox;


        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["bbsConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            Con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update tblAvailable set intqty=@intQty, curprice=@curprice where intresortid=@intresortid and dtm=@dtm and strroomtype=@strroomtype", Con);



            // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtm", DateTime.ParseExact(dtm.Text.Trim(), "dd/M/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            GridView1.Visible = true;




        }

DisplyGridview();
```

}

Comment: Thanks @Kuldeep: I'll go with the answer above as I am not using row updating.